# jquery slide up/down not sliding at all

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery code:

```
$(".desc_div").slideUp();
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

which should slide up/down a html div on click

but its not doing anything at all

here is a fiddle with all code: http://jsfiddle.net/6wvg7/

Comment: You missed to add jQuery lib http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6wvg7/4/  check left top of the fiddle to choose the jquery versions

Comment: i am using <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 on my page and its not working

Comment: do you use $(document).ready(); ???

Answer (score 1):

You didnt load any jquery in your jsfiddle.

please check the following image..

[image]

I already updated the code.

Please check the following link..

jsfiddle.net/6wvg7/1/

when you are working on your page then load the jquery using `<script>` tag and in your javascript use the following code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".desc_div").slideUp();
    $(".open_div").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/6wvg7/2/ try this out

You hadn't included jQuery in the fiddle and added a load handler to the paage

`$(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attached the jquery plugin, Check this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".desc_div").slideUp();
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow");
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/6wvg7/3/

Answer (score 0):

What ever code you wrote is correct. You have to include `jquery.js` file
This is the update js link check once http://jsfiddle.net/6wvg7/5/